# C# Get value of XmlNode object

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc

`XmlNode` objects are supposed to have a `Value` property, as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.value?view=net-5.0), but I'm having trouble accessing it.  I have serialized an XML string into this class:

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class requisitionsRequisition
{
    public object start_date { get; set; }
    public object end_date { get; set; }
    public object title { get; set; }
}
```

Here's where I do the work:

```
using (var reader = new StringReader(content))
{
    var deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(requisitionsRequisition), new XmlRootAttribute("requisitionsRequisition"));

    var r = (requisitionsRequisition)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);

    return View("Index", r);
 }
```

Here's a screenshot of what I see in my debugger.  I can't access value, it doesn't exist.  My types are wrong somehow.

When I try to access the Title property, it tells me the type is `{System.Xml.XmlNode[1]}` but when I try to use the `Value` property, it tells me it doesn't exist.

[image]

*Sorry, I know you guys on here hate screenshots  :)*

Comment: The code *does not* show a single variable/property of type `XmlNode` - are you sure you posted code you meant to?

Comment: Yeah, why does it say that title is of type XmlNode in the debugger? Or am i reading that wrong?

Comment: Variable of type `object` can point to object of any type... including `XmlNode`...

Comment: Ok that makes sense.  So how could I get the value from these properties?  Any ideas?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov You're comment was enough to get me to the answer.  :)  I'll update!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **Alexei Levenkov** pointed out in the comments.  The **type** of the requisitionsRequisition properties was of a generic `Object`.

I couldn't access the Value property because the type was no longer `XmlNode`.  I simply cast back to XmlNode and I can access the values easily now.

I changed this:

```
var title = r.requisitions[0].title
```

to this:

```
var title = (XmlNode[])r.requisition[0].title;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

**VS 2017 / VS 2019**

**Add Reference to System.Xml.Serialization**

- In VS menu, click **Project**
- Select **Add Reference**
- Check **System.Xml.Serialization**
- Click **OK**

**Add using statement**: `using System.Xml.Serialization;`

**Create class**: requisitionsRequisition

- In VS menu, click **Project**
- Select **Add Class** (name: requisitionsRequisition)

**Add using statement**: `using System.Xml.Serialization;`

**requisitionsRequisition.cs**

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public class requisitionsRequisition
{
    [XmlElementAttribute(ElementName = "start_date")]
    public object start_date { get; set; }

    [XmlElementAttribute(ElementName = "end_date")]
    public object end_date { get; set; }

    [XmlElementAttribute(ElementName = "title")]
    public object title { get; set; }
}
```

**Create class**: HelperXml

- In VS menu, click **Project**
- Select **Add Class** (name: HelperXml)

**Add using statement**: `using System.Xml.Serialization;`

**HelperXml.cs**

```
public static T DeserializeXMLFileToObject<T>(string xmlFilename)
{
    T rObject = default(T);

    try
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlFilename))
        {
            return default(T);
        }

        using (System.IO.StreamReader xmlStream = new System.IO.StreamReader(xmlFilename))
        {
            //create new instance
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

            //deserialize - read XML file
            rObject = (T)serializer.Deserialize(xmlStream);
        }

    }//try
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }//catch

    return rObject;
}

public static void SerializeObjectToXMLFile(object obj, string xmlFilename)
{
    try
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlFilename))
        {
            return;
        }//if

        using (System.IO.TextWriter xmlStream = new System.IO.StreamWriter(xmlFilename))
        {
            //create new instance
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());

            //serialize - write XML file
            serializer.Serialize(xmlStream, obj);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

**Usage**: (Serialize) - Write file

```
string filename = @"C:\Temp\XmlFile1.xml";

requisitionsRequisition r1 = new requisitionsRequisition();
r1.title = "This is my title";

//write to file
HelperXml.SerializeObjectToXMLFile(r1, filename);
```

**Usage**: (Deserialize) - Read file

```
string filename = @"C:\Temp\XmlFile1.xml";

//read from file
requisitionsRequisition r2 = HelperXml.DeserializeXMLFileToObject<requisitionsRequisition>(filename);

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("title: " + r2.title.ToString());
```